# CSS Flexbox bug with Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour with Flexbox on Firefox (latest).

It seems to happen in a very special case, when a child element of a flex item, has an absolute positioned element inside it.

I've created a codepen demo, it works fine in Chrome, however, on Firefox, you'll see that the image disappears.

The demo is at its simplest form. So should be pretty straight forward to know what I'm trying to do (tip: chrome)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwBaLJ

You'll see that the `.Item-media` element is set to `position: relative;` with a `img` inside it, set to `position: absolute;`

Has anyone experienced this on firefox and managed to find a decent solution?

**Important!** It's a responsive demo, only the mobile version doesn't work in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing your '...'-flex css

```
-moz-box-flex: $values
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/